# How to rotate all the images to the same orientation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to do image classification task and want to make sure my input data all have the same orientation.
The code bellow did not match all the images to the same directions and some flipped wrongly.
I will be thankful if anyone can help me with this matter, Thank you
[original image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxoTu.png)
[original image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NX5qE.png)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def getSubImage(rect, image):
    center, size, theta = rect
    center, size = tuple(map(int, center)), tuple(map(int, size))
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D( center, theta, 1)
    dst = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, src.shape[:2])
    out = cv2.getRectSubPix(dst, size, center)
    return out

image = cv2.imread('orginal1.png')
im_bw = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(im_bw, (5,5), 0)
im_bw = cv2.Canny(blur, 10, 90)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(im_bw, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contours[0])

out = getSubImage(rect, image)
cv2.imwrite('rotedorginal1.jpg', out)
plt.imshow(out)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please indent your code correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to build the matrix that rotates the image the right angle using `cv2.getRotationMatrix2D` and applying the operation with the matrix using `cv2.warpAffine`:

```
(x, y), (w, h), angle = cv2.minAreaRect(contours[0])
result = cv2.warpAffine(image, cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((image.shape[1]//2, image.shape[0]//2), angle-90, 1), (image.shape))
```

The code above transforms this image:

[image: Original image]

into this one:

[image: Rotated image]

Comment: Thank you Carlos. when I run the above code some images will be corrected vertically and some will remain horizontally. What we need is to make all images vertically

Comment: The rotation angle is controlled by the second parameter in the getRotationMatrix2D((x,y), angle, scale). I used angle-90 for the example above, but you may need to find the value that rotates correctly all your images. Also, take into account that the angle calculated by the minAreaRect function may be the opposite from what you think (rotated 180 degrees). That is why it is not easy to calculate the function for the angle with just one example. Also, the 0 degree reference for OpenCV is the 90 degree axis in the unit circle, the y axis so to speak. That requires additional work in the angle.

Comment: Yes I'm trying that now. Also, im trying to rotate based on axis y and x which could give better results. Thank you

Comment: Ibra, if my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer, thanks!